# Inserting mysql entry if doesn't exist, updating if it does exist java

Tags: java, mysql

I'm wanting to insert an entry if it does not exist otherwise update the entry, I couldn't use the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, I got confused with the syntax. So I tried to do something like this:

```
    final String QUERY = "REPLACE INTO skills SET VALUES (" + insert(player) + ") WHERE playername = '" + player.getUsername() + "'";
    statement.execute(QUERY);

    statement.close();
    connection.close();
}

private static String insert(Player player) {
    String stringToReturn = "'" + player.getUsername() + "',";
    for (int index = 0; index < 25; index++) {
        stringToReturn += player.getSkills().getLevels()[index] + "," + ((int) player.getSkills().getXp()[index]) + ",";
    }
    stringToReturn = stringToReturn.substring(0, stringToReturn.length() - 1);
    return stringToReturn;
}
```

But that's incorrect syntax so I was wondering how I could do this?

playername is primary key

Comment: `UPDATE` instead of `REPLACE`......?

Comment: No because then it won't insert the entry when it doesn't exist?

Comment: Show us your table structure

Comment: "*I couldn't use the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, I got confused with the syntax*" - so why isn't your question about how to fix the syntax of that command?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/DmyJBeRQ

Comment: @eggyal because I wasn't sure it worked how I wanted it to, thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct syntax to make ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE work for you is:

```
"INSERT INTO skills (playerName, otherColumn) 
    VALUES ('" + player.getUsername() + "', '" + insert(player) +"')
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE otherColumn = VALUES(otherColumn)";
```

Comment: Thanks, what's it mean by otherColumn? I'm really not familiar with MySQL syntax :( like, the insert function contains all values for all the different columns

Comment: You can say to the insert what are the columns that you want to insert in. And in your case, you were passing two columsn to the REPLACE. Since i didn't know the name of the other column i called it otherColumn. You would have to change it to the name of the column where you want to insert   "insert(player)" value

Comment: @user1009569. Now that i saw your schemma, if you want to insert for all those fields and update on all those fields, you have to write a big query for that, but as long as you have the playerName inthere, the thought process is the same.

Comment: The insert method returns a string which contains each value for each column.

Comment: So should VALUES only have one value in the brackets, why when I use INSERT INTO table Values(2, 3, 6, 34, 5, 96) it will insert all of them values?

Comment: I'm severely confused haha.

Comment: You add the column names before VALUES, then you put the values you want to insert into those columns in VALUES, then ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1 = values(col1), col2 = values(col2). But probably you could do this easier with REPLACE INTO, but you would always have to give it all the values, since replace into deletes and inserts a new record in the table.

Comment: So how would I do this for my table? Would I have to have: "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE otherColumn = VALUES(otherColumn)"; for every column?

Comment: See this example for a start on how to do the ON DUPLICATE KEY or the REPLACE INTO. You still have to add the rest of the columns, but this is how you do it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3a8f. Remove one or the other and run the select to see that either one does what you are trying to do :)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Do I still need the Insert into bit?

Comment: Or would it just be like: REPLACE INTO `skills` (
   `playerName` ,
   `Attacklvl`,
   `Attackxp`,
   `Defencelvl`, 
   `Defencexp`)
 VALUES ('JOHNY',
         2,
         3,
         4,
         5)
          
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  `Attacklvl` = VALUES(`Attacklvl`),
  `Attackxp` = VALUES(`Attackxp`),
  `Defencelvl` = VALUES(`Defencelvl`), 
  `Defencexp` = VALUES(`Defencexp`);

Comment: Dont use them together. Use either REPLCAE INTO or INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY. that is mixed. REPLACE INTO ends afther the VALUES(...);

Comment: if the variable columns contains all the columns you want to insert and "insert(player" has all the values to fill those columns, then it should be correct

Comment: try writing the string to log, to see what is in there.

Comment: I didn't validate all of it, but you shouldn't have an update for playername. that is the primary key, so that will not change, but besides that, it looks promising.

Comment: Oh right, You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''skills' ('playername','Attacklvl','Attackxp','Defencelvl','Defencexp','Strength' at line 1